# Save user form and profile in one Django CBV

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to save two forms in one class-based view. The forms are the classic user form and profile form with a `Profile`'s user attribute pointing back at User with a `user = models.OneToOneField()` in the models.

`views.py`:

```
class ProfileEdit(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile_edit')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileEdit, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
        context['forms'] = [user_form, profile_form]
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(self.request, "Your profile was updated.")
            return redirect(reverse('profile_edit'))
        else:
            return super(ProfileEdit, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

On a basic get request, I get

```
'NoneType' object is not callable
```

That's because I don't provide a `form_class`, but I don't want to declare `form_class` because I have two forms. I declare those forms in the `post` method. Should I subclass `FormView` or is there something better to use?

Also, Is `get_context_data` the right place to instantiate the forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two forms in one:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # magic 
        self.user = kwargs['instance'].user
        user_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        user_kwargs['instance'] = self.user
        self.user_form = UserForm(*args, **user_kwargs)
        # magic end 

        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields.update(self.user_form.fields)
        self.initial.update(self.user_form.initial)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_form.save(*args, **kwargs)
        return super(ProfileForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. My ultimate goal was to not declaratively re-specify the User model fields, but I noticed this kind of hijacking removes validation. I get a 500 error and had to define my own `def clean_username` for uniqueness and valid characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options here but i would just use a simple TemplateView or similar

Instantiate the forms in get and post with the appropriate params

```
    def get(...):
        self.user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
        self.profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
        return super().get(...)

    def post(...)
        self.user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        self.profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if valid:
          save_stuff()
          return redirect()
        return render_to_response(...) or super().get(...)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileEdit, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['forms'] = [self.user_form, self.profile_form]
        return context
```

Then get_context_data will not handle logic for get or post

Comment: Kind of working, but invalid usernames, e.g. "myusername\" slip through. Traceback: `Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/profile/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'profile_detail' with arguments '(u'myusername\\',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<username>[-\\w]+)/$']` It comes from a named URL for the profile permalink in my nav: `{% url 'profile_detail' user.username %}` I don't know why the forms aren't validating.